# NPM ERR! code 1 when installing any packages on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, npm-install

I don't know what changed on my windows PC, but I can't install any packages on my PC right now. I tried installing these packages today:

npm install needle

npm install got

npm install oauth-1.0a

and I received very similar error messages. I didn't have this problem before so I'm really confused as to why i'm having these errors now.

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! git dep preparation failed
npm ERR! command C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\Tyree\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js install --force --cache=C:\Users\Tyree\AppData\Local\npm-cache --prefer-offline=false --prefer-online=false --offline=false --no-progress --no-save --no-audit --include=dev --include=peer --include=optional --no-package-lock-only --no-dry-run
npm ERR! > wyvern-schemas@0.14.1 prepublish
npm ERR! > scripts/build.sh
npm ERR! npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm ERR! npm WARN skipping integrity check for git dependency ssh://git@github.com/ProjectOpenSea/wyvern-js.git
npm ERR! npm WARN skipping integrity check for git dependency ssh://git@github.com/ahultgren/async-eventemitter.git
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.3.2: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated safe-event-emitter@1.0.1: Renamed to @metamask/safe-event-emitter
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated mkdirp-promise@5.0.1: This package is broken and no longer maintained. 'mkdirp' itself supports promises now, please switch to that.
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated nomnom@1.8.1: Package no longer supported. Contact support@npmjs.com for more info.
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated multibase@0.7.0: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated multibase@0.6.1: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.1: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated multicodec@0.5.7: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.14.3: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated ethereumjs-block@2.2.2: New package name format for new versions: @ethereumjs/block. Please update.
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated eth-sig-util@1.4.2: Deprecated in favor of '@metamask/eth-sig-util'
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated ethereumjs-block@2.2.2: New package name format for new versions: @ethereumjs/block. Please update.
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated uuid@2.0.1: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated ethereumjs-tx@2.1.2: New package name format for new versions: @ethereumjs/tx. Please update.
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated ethereumjs-tx@2.1.2: New package name format for new versions: @ethereumjs/tx. Please update.
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated ethashjs@0.0.8: New package name format for new versions: @ethereumjs/ethash. Please update.
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated ethereumjs-blockchain@4.0.4: New package name format for new versions: @ethereumjs/blockchain. Please update.
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.2.1: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated ethereumjs-tx@1.3.7: New package name format for new versions: @ethereumjs/tx. Please update.
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated ethereumjs-vm@2.6.0: New package name format for new versions: @ethereumjs/vm. Please update.
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated ethereumjs-block@1.7.1: New package name format for new versions: @ethereumjs/block. Please update.
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated multicodec@1.0.4: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated ethereumjs-common@1.5.2: New package name format for new versions: @ethereumjs/common. Please update.
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated ethereumjs-account@3.0.0: Please use Util.Account class found on package ethereumjs-util@^7.0.6 https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-util/releases/tag/v7.0.6
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated ethereumjs-block@2.2.2: New package name format for new versions: @ethereumjs/block. Please update.
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated axios@0.17.1: Critical security vulnerability fixed in v0.21.1. For more information, see https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/3410
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated ethereumjs-tx@2.1.2: New package name format for new versions: @ethereumjs/tx. Please update.
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated cids@0.7.5: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated ethereumjs-vm@4.2.0: New package name format for new versions: @ethereumjs/vm. Please update.
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.4 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm ERR! 'scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
npm ERR! operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! npm ERR! path C:\Users\Tyree\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\git-clonemSjZbY
npm ERR! npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c scripts/build.sh
npm ERR!
npm ERR! npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! npm ERR!     C:\Users\Tyree\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-10-19T19_46_18_861Z-debug-0.log

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Tyree\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-10-19T19_46_17_124Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Try to create a new folder then run all over again like starting from npm init & npm install express... etc, install package one by one. Then copy your codes to new server.js/app.js. Version of package sometimes will give problem.

Comment: I gave up on using npm. tried yarn add and it works like a charm. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try Uninstalling and Re-installing Node to the latest Stable Version.

Comment: i just uninstalled and reinstalled to the latest version of Nodejs, but still getting the error. this is driving me nuts.